# 'MediaPlayer Error Code 4003 extra 0' on Leanback Exoplayer Library

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-tv, leanback

I'm using

```
 implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:extension-leanback:2.18.2'
```

for VOD playing in Android TV. But facing getting Media error code 4003 in some of device like MI-TV
[image: error toast]

**All device doesn't throw the exception . Checked Samsung TV and Emulator TV ,it's worked well but in some MI-BOX this exception is occurring **

How do i fix it?